# Slow kernel boot time

Tags: boot, kernel, initramfs

I installed kubuntu 22.04 today and I'm having a longer boot time compared to windows 10.

```
$ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 9.167s (kernel) + 4.729s (userspace) = 13.897s 
graphical.target reached after 4.367s in userspace
```

Is this normal for a SATA 3 SSD ?

Also I'm posting these in case they help:

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain 
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @4.367s
└─multi-user.target @4.366s
  └─smartmontools.service @1.641s +2.724s
    └─basic.target @1.403s
      └─sockets.target @1.403s
        └─uuidd.socket @1.403s
          └─sysinit.target @1.395s
            └─systemd-timesyncd.service @1.297s +97ms
              └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @1.187s +58ms
                └─local-fs.target @1.176s
                  └─tmp.mount @1.173s +2ms
                    └─swap.target @1.158s
                      └─swap-swapfile.swap @1.126s +26ms
                        └─swap.mount @1.073s +34ms
                          └─dev-sda6.device @167ms +895ms
```

Is it OK to disable `smartmontools.service` ?

```
$ cat /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf 
#
# initramfs.conf
# Configuration file for mkinitramfs(8). See initramfs.conf(5).
#
# Note that configuration options from this file can be overridden
# by config files in the /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d directory.

#
# MODULES: [ most | netboot | dep | list ]
#
# most - Add most filesystem and all harddrive drivers.
#
# dep - Try and guess which modules to load.
#
# netboot - Add the base modules, network modules, but skip block devices.
#
# list - Only include modules from the 'additional modules' list
#

MODULES=dep

#
# BUSYBOX: [ y | n | auto ]
#
# Use busybox shell and utilities.  If set to n, klibc utilities will be used.
# If set to auto (or unset), busybox will be used if installed and klibc will
# be used otherwise.
#

BUSYBOX=auto

#
# COMPRESS: [ gzip | bzip2 | lz4 | lzma | lzop | xz | zstd ]
#

COMPRESS=lz4

#
# DEVICE: ...
#
# Specify a specific network interface, like eth0
# Overridden by optional ip= or BOOTIF= bootarg
#

DEVICE=

#
# NFSROOT: [ auto | HOST:MOUNT ]
#

NFSROOT=auto

#
# RUNSIZE: ...
#
# The size of the /run tmpfs mount point, like 256M or 10%
# Overridden by optional initramfs.runsize= bootarg
#

RUNSIZE=10%

#
# FSTYPE: ...
#
# The filesystem type(s) to support, or "auto" to use the current root
# filesystem type
#

FSTYPE=auto
```

I **Switched to lz4 and used MODULES=dep** compression, but didn't help

Here is the output of `dmesg` just after boot: https://paste.debian.net/1241082/

Comment: 15 seconds isn't absurd. I have Arch (with a minimal configuration) and that takes maybe 20 seconds to boot, including the Grub menu (enabled) on my NVME drive. But 15 seconds isn't crazy, so I'm not sure how much faster you will really be able to get it. The DE will take some time as well, so I always boot to a TTY and don't use a Display Manager and just run `startx` to launch the display. But 15 seconds isn't that long, and the time that you spend optimizing it will likely exceed the time you are waiting for it to boot. You can try, just don't expect it to be a huge improvement.

Comment: "I installed kubuntu 22.04 today and I'm having a longer boot time compared to windows 10." Make 100% sure you compare using equal situations: Windows defaults to hibernation. Ubuntu does not.  Turn fast boot off in Windows and try again. 14, 15 seconds -can- be the a correct time, Turn off `smartmontools`.... yes but booting happens in parallel not subsequently. It might help to tell us what the read/write speed it of the ssd. That way we can compare ;-) Mine boots in 10s.

Comment: You could also try compiling the kernel yourself and disabling everything you don't need, which could shrink it a bunch. It isn't that hard. I'd take the normal kernel from kernel.org, and copy the existing kernel config over, and disable everything you don't need. Although keep a backup kernel (and know how to access it!) in case something goes wrong. There is quite a bit in the default kernel that you could theoretically remove to make it smaller. If you have (for example) a CPU from a few years ago, no GPU, and all common hardware and use Ethernet, you can disable quite a bit.